# is Functor used for defining properties of mapping and how to define a mapping's properties in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am confused about using Functor

is Functor used for defining properties of mapping and how to write a mapping's properties in Haskell?

if so, can haskell be used to generate function or other things after definition written

Malformed head of type or class declaration: flow x y

```
   import Control.Applicative

class flow x y where { f :: x y -> x; } // this line i do not know whether is enforced to write
                                        // how to write this map 

instance flow Int Int where
 flow t flow(s, p) = flow(t+s, p)
 flow 0 p = p
```

if there are more runnable example rather than the definition of the haskell, it would be better

when i replace properties in example found in google, usually can not run, or fragments

when use example about mapping, for example A -> B, there are data A data B defined first, but do not know why use data as a type defined, when i read category theory, there are arrows and objects
both are Hom, Functor is from Hom to Hom, does it mean data represent Hom?

When compare with software Singular, i become more confusing. Hom is a operation of kontraHom and Kohom and take two matrix.

Do Hom have different meaning in Haskell and Singular

Comment: **1.** Do you know what is a type class? **2.** Are you redefining Functor?

Comment: Your code looks strange to me. What do you try to archieve?

Comment: Your code isn't valid Haskell. And it is confusingly invalid. What are you trying to write?

Comment: I just want to define a mapping's properties and use it

Comment: Hi Super G. - is your first exposure to Haskell via academic papers? From the code you've posted in the last couple of days it looks like you are confusing the "proofs by induction" often presented in papers on Haskell with actual Haskell code. Usually - though not always - proofs are type set in italics. They are not runnable as Haskell code. Unfortunately for newcomers, Haskell code is also often typeset in italics too, though the formatting is quite different. With a little experience it is easy to spot the difference.

Comment: I read haskell wiki and find some examples to run, as you said, most of them are not runnable, so far i can not find an example to do mapping properties, or how to use functor , i update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Singular is a computer algebra system. Haskell is a programming language which computer algebra can be implemented within. You need to start simply and just learn basic Haskell syntax and concepts before trying to see the categorical/algebriac picture, especially since different elements can be implemented in different ways.

But let's try something simple to establish a common language. The notes I give here should be consistent with the treatment here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory

One approach is to describe the category `Hask`. The objects of `Hask` are all Haskell types. `Hask` contains function types, as well as pairs, so it is cartesian closed, and all its arrows are isomorphic to objects. In categorical terms, a hom-set is the collection of all morphisms between two objects. So the hom-set on (Int,Float) is the collection of all functions that turn an Int into a Float.

Categorically, a functor between categories X and Y sends the objects of X to Y and the arrows of X to Y. It also therefore sends the hom-sets (collections of arrows) of X to Y.

The class `Functor` in Haskell provides part of what you get with a categorical functor. It provides an operation `fmap` that sends arrows on objects in `Hask` to arrows on some other category (which, in our case, must also be composed of *some* objects from Hask). It can send functions on values to functions on lists of values, or functions on values to functions on pairs which contain values, etc.

All that said, I would recommend learning Haskell without thinking about writing type classes or instances at all for some time. Stick to explicit data declarations and functions until you're more comfortable with the basic features of the language.

Answer (score 1):

As an attempt at addressing the immediate confusion, a Haskell Functor defines a structure you can 'map' over, by specifying an implementation of 'fmap' (so yes, in Haskell you could use an instance of the Functor type class in order to specify an implementation of fmap for your specific structure)

Your provided code is problematic in two ways: i) A functor is already provided by Haskell (no need to redefine the class; instead you want to define an 'instance' of the Functor class), and ii) you need to adhere to the Functor interface.

Though I may suggest a more comprehensive resource (highly recommended is the book "Real World Haskell"), if you absolutely need to know more about how to deal with Haskell's instantiation of Functors, an excellent article is http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monads_as_containers
(every Monad is a Functor).